# Moz rendering bottom property differently than Webkit

Tags: css, browser, mozilla

Trying to display an H3 on hover using the following CSS on this [site](http://mtthwbsh.com/sta499):

```
 a > h3 {
 min-width: 100% !important;
 min-height: 100px;
 max-height: 100px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -80px;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 25px 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
 transition: all 300ms ease-in;

 a:hover > h3 {
 bottom: 0;
 }
```

For some reason this is not rendering the same in Firefox as it is in Chrome and Safari. Looks to be an issue with the bottom attribute.

Comment: This actually seems to be an issue with the height. Chrome lists the item as 50px tall, FF lists it as 100px. I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason safari is calculating "min-width" as 250px and firefox as 100%!

So the box layout turns out 250x100 in safari (ok) but 240x50 in firefox. That could be the problem. Where is that 100% coming from (perhaps somewhere in isotope's js files?)

Comment: Well, the box is set to min-width 100%, and the containing div is 250px wide so this would make sense. It should be 100px high, not seeing in Firefox where it is rendering as 50px?

Comment: Sorry, it's the opposite. The <h3> div, when inspecting with safari's Web Inspector tool, reveals a box with 240x50px. In Firefox, when inspecting it with firebug, reveals a box with 250x100px.

Comment: Ah, I'll check this out further. I believe the height is set at 100px to reveal the top part of the box, something isn't rendering correctly in Firefox that's causing it to sit above the photo.

Comment: It might be something in Isotope javascript files that is overriding the CSS. If you find that the answer has helped please vote up ;) thanks

Comment: It's pointed me in the right direction either way, I think I can give it a go from here. Thanks!